# In MongoDB, When I trying to import the JSON file by the mongoimport utility in mongo shell, But I am getting the error message

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB, When I trying to import the JSON file by the mongoimport utility in mongo shell, But I am getting the error message.

```
error message - 2014-07-22T17:33:57.659+0530 SyntaxError: Unexpected token %
```

Where I need to execute the mongoimport  --db command. I am able to execute the ./mongoimpor

Comment: Can you post complete command which you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Run the *mongoimport* command from outside the mongo shell. Ideally, it should be run from the folder where the json file is located. More information on *mongoimport* can be found here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/.